# Generating JHipster Gateway without server code but with client websocket support

Tags: websocket, microservices, jhipster, stomp, gateway

I'm using JHipster to generate a microservice application made of

- a `gateway` application with UI and without server: option `--skip-server`
- a `gateway` application without UI and with server: option `--skip-client`
- some microservices (type `microservice`

In order to generate everything I'm using a `jdl` file which looks like this:

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType gateway,
    websocket spring-websocket,
    clientFramework angularX,
    skipServer true,
    ....
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    applicationType gateway,
    packageName com.fginc.hermes.front,
    websocket spring-websocket,
    skipClient true
    ...
  }
  entities *
}

application {
  config {
    applicationType microservice,
  }
  entities A,B
}

application {
  config {
    applicationType microservice,
  }
  entities B,C
}

/** my entities **/
```

Everything works fine excepts that I would like the Angular websocket code (user-tracker) to be generated on the pure UI application.

Thank you for your help

Comment: FWIW, you're doing it the hard way by using `--skip-client` and `--skip-server`. I'd recommend trying to generate a gateway without these first. Then you can get everything working and split it up later.

Comment: Hello @MattRaible thank you for your answer. That's what I did and it works fine.

Comment: By the way Jhipster is a great tool !!